# horizontal drag on mobile safari

Tags: mobile, safari, drag, responsive-design

Maybe I'm afflicted with myopia and just can't see what's wrong anymore but I have some weird horizontal drag going on in mobile safari only (i checked it on a browser and on my android phone and it's working fine.) I'm wondering if anyone has any insight as to how to prevent this from happening? The link to the site is [yetisandbox](http://yeti.yetisandbox.com)

maybe it's a viewport issue? I'm using this currently:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this too. This fixed it for me:

```
html, body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I should mention this is after I implemented the above meta tag that was posted in the original question. That keeps the user from scaling, but I still had a horizontal drag. You need to make sure there are no elements sticking out making the page larger than the iOS max width size. Set everything to 100% or less. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for the followup @jrue. I can confirm for anyone having this problem its elements sticking out the viewport so checking all widths and correcting html will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
.home-trail{
  ...
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  ...
}
.home-intro{
  ...
  width: 1170px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  ...
}
```

your .home-trail container has a width of 100% and an absolute position. Its parent .home-intro may have a width smaller than the viewport width but is position static. because of that the 100% doesn't refer to .home-intro width. So its 100vw but gets a left distance because the margin-left of its parent plus a missing left:0 property.